# Confirm Dialog showing up multiple times

Tags: java, swing, jtable, joptionpane, listselectionlistener

I have a confirm dialog inside a addListSelectionListener. This fires when I select a row in the table. Then the confirm dialog appears and after I click yes or no it keeps on appearing!

This is my code.

```
public Reference() {
    initComponents();
    fillTable();
    jTable1.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            int prompt = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to Check Out this item?", "Warning", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if (prompt == 0) {
                String accessNo = jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString();
                String query = "delete from reference where accessNo=" + accessNo + "";
                if (DB.executeNonQuery(query) > 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Check out Successfull!");
                    fillTable();
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Check out Failed!");
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that the value is not adjusting in the `ListSelectionListener`

```
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
   if(!e.getValueAdjusting()) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Ref: [How to Write a List Selection Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html)